# C++ - Replace special characters from file with non ascii characters

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I'm having a difficult time replacing some characters from my file with some diacritics from my mother tongue ; such as:

```
character_to_replace      replacement
    º                      ș
    ª                      Ș
    þ                      ț
    Þ                      Ț
```

I've found the Unicode for the character_to_replace but for some reason the file won't save to the expected output. I figured out it's something to do with the UTF-8 and unicode conversion. However i managed to print out the characters but only to the console when i try to write to the file it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
void replace(string &source, string to_replace, string replacement)
{
    int found = 0;
    string auxiliar;
    auxiliar = source;

    while (found != string::npos)
    {
        found = auxiliar.find(to_replace);

        if (found != -1)
        {
            source.replace(found, 1, replacement);
            auxiliar = auxiliar.substr(found + to_replace.size());
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << endl;

    string line;
    ifstream file;
    ofstream send_line;

    send_line.open("out.txt");
    file.open("in.txt");

    while (!file.eof())
    {
        getline(file, line);
        replace(line, "\u00b0", "\u0219");
        replace(line, "\u00aa", "\u0218");
        replace(line, "\u00fe", "\u021b");
        replace(line, "\u00de", "\u021a");
        send_line << line << "\n";
    }

    file.close();
    send_line.close();
}
```

Can you point me to the right direction where I may solve this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What system are you using?

It looks like the file you're processing may be encoded in UTF8, but the ≤ character isn't in the codeset underlying the locale you're using.

Try running the command locale to see what locale you are using. If the LC_CTYPE entry does not end in something like UTF-8, you might try the command:
locale -a
to get a list of locales available and look for something that fits you language and location with a UTF-8 codeset. The locale names aren't standardized, but a common convention is to have a 2 letter code for your language, an underscore, a 2 letter country code, a period, and a code set identifier. The locale I use much of the time is en_US.UTF-8 (English, United States of America, UTF-8) on OS X and the above commands work without error in this locale.

You can use the environment variables LANG and LC_* to set the locale for standard utilities that you run. Good applications will set the locale they use to be controlled by the environment variables. If you are using applications that don't set their locale based on what the user requests, they will problem be run in the C or POSIX Locale.

Please follow this link 
http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/220029-remove-replace-non-ascii-character-file.html